# Check if database table column value is greater than or equal to the current date

Tags: php, mysql, date, comparison

How can I comparison date as dd/mm/YY. I want to get data from db greater than or equal the current date ; Code like this

```
$current_date = date("d/m/Y");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE date>='".current_date."'");
```

But it doesn't work?

Comment: what date format you are using in you database??

Comment: This really depends on how your date is stored in your database. If its in the `d/m/Y` format then someone really messed up from the start

Comment: varchar combine as $day."/".$month."/".$year in php and save db

Comment: @regxcode to store your date into your database use `date` field and in you insert query use `NOW()` so that you will enter the right format and datatype into your database.

Comment: thank you @jogesh_p ok I convert field as date in db  but I getting date from form  with select tag for day and month year text input.After combine these in php and store db.Can I store that string as date?Or convert it too in php

Comment: @regxcode, in your DB the date format is like `YYYY-MM-DD`, so set this format form select tag and insert it into your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use php time in MySQL if there is no serious reasons for it. In your situation the best way is `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE date>=NOW()`